# How does DNA damage cause ageing in yeast?

Tags: yeast, dna-damage

As I understand it, in yeast ageing there is daughter cell and mother cell. The daughter cell is has newly "fresh" DNA and mother cell dies after some counts of replication.

What happens to the accumulated DNA damage in the yeast mother cell?

One of theory of human ageing is accumulation of damage in nuclear DNA. The daughter yeast cell is clone of mother, and has same DNA. What happens with this damage?

**Edit to simplify:** Why is the DNA damage not transferred at all to the daughter cell? The repair mechanism in humans is evidently not perfect, because DNA damage is one of major ageing theories. So if we die from this, how do yeast get around the detrimental affects of DNA damage that cause ageing in humans?

Comment: I can tell there is a good question here somewhere, but its hard to figure out exactly what you are asking. Are you asking if the DNA damage is transferred to the daughter cell? If you edit to clear up the question you'll probably get a good answer. Currently it sounds like you want to know about DNA damage repair.

Comment: I am asking about why there is no DNA damage transfer at all, to daughter cell. I wrote about the theory of damage in aging, so it couldn't be in any way question about repair - because if there was good repair - it wouldn't be in aging theory. I edited the question.

Comment: Unfortunately it is becoming less and less clear what you want to know. There are some assumptions your have made that are wrong compounded by difficult grammar. Furthermore ageing is a wildly understudied area of research. DNA damage is a very complex and broad field with a lot of case studies, science, and history behind it. Specifically: "Aging in yeast (and other eukaryotic) and DNA damage" is a massive topic. It sounds like you want to know everything there is to know about it, which is not suitable for this forum and the question could get closed after the bounty ends.

Comment: I have made an edit, feel free to roll back, but the grammar at least is much clearer, maybe someone will be able to grapple the question now.

Comment: Thank you Good Gravy. I just restore back the title, because I am asking about DNA only and not about all the aging process.

Comment: It is good practice to use a question rather than a statement title (only on these forums).

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing mutation caused ageing with DNA damage repair caused ageing?

Comment: I used only the world damage. No meter what damage. Some damage to DNA that leads to cell aging (loss of some activity) and death.

Comment: This is a massive question with a few key misunderstandings of the terminology, which to be fair is complicated in the field of ageing. OP kept moving the goal posts of what the question was (as can be seen in the comments for both answers), and I doubt any answer will be good enough.

Answer (score 5):

In eukaryotic cells there is no difference between a mother and a daughter cell - the later is an exact copy of the mother cell. This is true for yeasts as well for example for human cells. The only thing that happens over time is that the telomeres at the end of the chromosomes get shorter (unless the cell has an active telomerase which most cells doesn't) and it reaches the [Hayflick limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayflick_limit) where every further division will lead to a shortage of coding chromosmal regions and thus cause problems. If cells do not acquire any other chromosomal damage and have enough ressources, this would be the limit for their lifetime.

Of course there are DNA damages occuring over time. Most of them are either repaired by the highly efficient DNA damage repair system of eukaryotic cells, which consists of different checkpoints during the cell cycle. These checkpoints are located at transition between the different  phases of the [cell cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_cycle). If a DNA damage is identified, the cell cycle is stopped to enable a DNA damage repair by special proteins and to prevent that damaged cells undergo mitosis (here the [G2-M checkpoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G2-M_DNA_damage_checkpoint) is important). This works schematically like in this figure (from the Wikipedia article on [DNA repair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_repair)):

[image]

If the DNA damage cannot be resolved, cells will either go into senescence (basically go into a permanent dormant state) or undergo apoptosis. If there are damages which are (for whatever reasons) are either not spotted or occur during the repair of DNA double strand breaks by non-homologous end joining, these are then replicated and inherited by further generations. Unless these errors occur during the replication process mother and daughter cells are genetically identical.

So eukaryotic cells acquire DNA damage over time (one of the reasons why late pregnancies pose a greater risk than early), but we are different from yeast in one point: Yeast has an active telomerase, which is not active in most of our cells (mainly except in stem cells). If the cells collect too much chromosmal damages than they will die.

The references listed below go deeper into the topic and are interesting to read.

References:

1. [Negative regulation of yeast telomerase activity through an
   interaction with an upstream region of the DNA primer](http://nar.oxfordjournals.org/content/26/6/1487.full)
2. [Cell cycle control in the kidney.](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3879/6827pimy_pdf.htm)
3. [The evolution of diverse biological responses to DNA damage:
   insights from yeast and p53](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3873/yxu4u4se_pdf.htm)
4. [DNA damage and decisions: CtIP coordinates DNA repair and cell cycle
   checkpoints](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3873/8dbvh7hd_pdf.htm)
5. [Cellular Responses to DNA Damage: One Signal, Multiple Choices](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3873/oli52vv2_pdf.htm)

Comment: Thank you Chris. But, like I wrote, one one the main theories of aging is DNA damage. So how is that? If the mechanism is so good, that keeping DNA of yeast fine for millions of years, why is in human its cause aging?

Comment: @Barbos you'll want to keep in mind the generation time of a yeast cell, vs. the generation time of a human being. The exact mechanisms or processes that are damaged and cause aging are under investigation. What you'll also want to consider is that yeasts and other multicellular eukaryotes have linear chromosomes that shorten with each replication at the telomere, and may become as above: cancerous, apoptotic or senescent. Check out the [NIH website](http://www.nia.nih.gov/health/publication/biology-aging/preface) for aging.

Comment: I also figure it useful to add that senescent cells secrete cytokines, ECM hydrolases etc. to aid in their timely removal by the immune system. If there's a declining immune system with age, I'd assume the ability to remove senescent cells would decrease. Of course, the regular secretion of hydrolases and inflammatory compounds will produce it's own array of damage that may lead to aging.

Comment: @kendall - no, it's not the answer. Cancer? Telomere? Declining immune system with age? It is not what I am asking about. And about "generation time" - you have some source that says that because of this, yeast cells have so much less DNA damage than human? There is cells in mammals that divide and die faster that some eukaryote organisms.

Comment: Also, what the connection with generation time? This DNA lives, no matter in old cell or in new, daughter cell. It's same DNA that influenced by environment.

Comment: The mechanism is really good - humans only generate only about 30 new mutations in their gametes per generation (I can look up the paper which makes this estimation if this is of interest for you). This is an incredible small number...this happens because of damages that cannot be repaired correctly or where the wrong strand is corrected.

Comment: Why the downvote? Can you explain whats wrong? I can only work on the answer when I know the criticism.

Comment: Because it's really not what I asked, I know about this mechanisms (but you will get the bounty - thank you for answers anyway), There are really few central aging theories (3 main), one of them is damage in DNA. (not only mutations). Also there is damage in mitochondrial DNA. (Radiation, radicals, environment and more) So this mechanisms isn't perfect but yeast need to have just perfect system... Much more stronger than ours. Because if we have damaged DNA in cell, cell die - we live. If yeast have damage - he die.

Comment: @Barbos I have edited the question now - does it answer your question better? If not, please let me know which parts are still unclear.

Comment: @Chris, thank you, but now its worse - because your first paragraph is fully wrong. There is difference between mother and daughter cell - there is asymmetric division in yeast, also there is indication that bacteria has same thing. But it doesn't meter for my question. Also it is fully wrong to say that all what happens is telomeres shorting, there IS accumulating DNA damage, this bring cancer and aging (the last is theoretical). So human die from this, but yeast no. Why?

Comment: Most of our cells are not developing into cancer cells - otherwise we all would die from it. Assymetric cells division leads to differently sized cells, but the genetic material will be the same. There are indeed some indications that this is different in prokaryotic cells, where the damage accumulates in one cell. This [article](http://genesdev.cshlp.org/content/23/23/2675.full) is interesting in this context.

Comment: No. No. That where my question coming from. The asymmetric division not lead to same cell! Because the cell of mother yeast AGING. And when we talking about aging, one of theories is accumulating DNA damage.

Comment: Then you should edit your question again to make clear what you really want.

Comment: All are in the question.  "Why there is no DNA damage transfer at all, to daughter cell?"

Comment: Your assumption is wrong - there a transfer of DNA damages to daughter cells. It's rare, though.

Comment: If the  transfer of DNA damages is rare - why is it one of major aging theories? I just say the same things again and aging ...

Comment: It was my understanding that it was unclear whether the shortening telomerase was a cause or an effect of ageing. Is there evidence that shows cause?

Answer (score 4):

## Background to the different theories of ageing.

[This video, from a senior lecturer at the University of Liverpool who specialises in ageing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jc4yK0zZ-cQ), discusses the theories of ageing. He touches on the DNA damage theory.

## DNA damage theory of ageing.

Note that when talking about DNA damage theory, we are specifically talking about damage to the process of cell renewal by DNA damage repair mechanisms in stem cells.

**Mutation ageing is not the same as DNA damage causing ageing and cannot really cause ageing in yeast.** The idea that cells [acquire damage over time due to mutated DNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_damage_theory_of_aging#Mutation_theories_of_aging) is fundamentally different to the DNA damage theory of ageing. The mechanisms that lead to DNA damage are covered very well in @Chris' answer.

The suggested systemic effect that DNA damage has in the human body causes an inability to renew cells due to a lack of viable stem cells. This contributes to the process of ageing in the organism.

In yeast, this stem cell depletion process does not happen (they are single cellular mostly). *In the comments it appears that you are actually talking about mutation based ageing in your original question.* Mutations are passed to daughter cells. But these daughter cells don't appear to age or to die quicker (If the parental cell is 5 days old, the daughter cell does not appear to be 5 days old). This is the fundamental reason why this form of ageing remains less studied - **it doesn't really make sense that general mutations cause ageing.**

## Summary

To directly answer the question: **"How does DNA damage cause ageing in yeast?"**

The question doesn't quite capture the whole picture and confuses DNA damage theory of animal ageing with general DNA damage at a cellular level.

There are many theories of ageing. Nobody knows which ones have more or less influence on ageing. Yeast is a good model for some kinds of age theory modelling, but perhaps not in the case of DNA damage based ageing. Although they experience DNA damage in the form of mutation, this doesn't cause ageing in the same way that DNA damage might cause ageing in humans because they are single celled organisms, and don't experience the same inter-tissue relationships that more complex organisms have.

---

## Edits

*This answer has been changed extensively since its first draft based on additional questions and queries from the OP in the comments. I decided to keep some important points that were raised and dismissed.*

> Why there is no DNA damage transfer at all, to daughter cell?

DNA damage can occur and ***is*** transferred to the daughter cell. Damage is very rare though.

> So how yeast survive? Human stem cells aging and die, or get cancer. But yeast no. Human start from one cell. And die. Yeast start from one cell and live forever (dividing again and again)

*Edit After Comments:*

**Single cell**

In yeast there are no inter-tissue systems. Mutated damage is simply passed on if the cell is viable. Also the assumption that they live forever isn't entirely accurate. But the DNA is passed on in its mutated or damaged form.

**Multi cell**

DNA damage based ageing is a big problem for animals. ([Dolle *et al* 2013](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/acel.12071/full)) Showed that DNA damage to a single repair pathway causes accelerated ageing, (but note that there was not an increase in mutation during this ageing).

> but you talking about cancer, it's not so good example, my mistake.  But in humans aging NOT like cancer - it occur in ALL the body and all the cells. So in all cells there are some DNA damage.

**Another edit:** You were right to talk about cancer in this context. The DNA damage theory of ageing is that small changes (damage) in our DNA accumulate over time and damage cell types by damaging various DNA repair pathways.

Damage accumulates and over time less [stem cells for renewal are viable and cellular repair of other damaged cells slows down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_damage_theory_of_aging#Long-lived_stem_cells).

Also this same fundamental principle of mutation damage happening over time can lead to mutations that switch off cell control mechanisms and lead to cancer. Although these these mutations do not increase in rate with age ([Hill *et al.,* 2005](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15690342)).

For example the naked mole rat lives 10 times that of comparable species (less ageing) and have not been observed to naturally acquire cancer (less cancer). The theory implies that the two things are quite linked because of the way DNA changes, but not that specifically mutation is a cause or result of ageing.

> I talking more about aging. Because there is aging in yeast. And one of aging theories for human - accumulating DNA damage. So what *Chris* writing is that it's really rare.

**Stem cells are damaged. ** I'm no longer entirely sure of what you mean by ageing in yeast. Yeast aren't reliant on a limited number of stem cells for cellular renewal, they don't age in the way you might be thinking. They simply proliferate the mutated cell type. There is no impact to a larger organism like in human ageing.

**DNA damage.** Yeast is a very helpful organism for understanding the underlying biochemistry and genetics of ageing, not the overall ageing systems. These are two different fields of study. It is unclear which you are talking about at this point.

> Also there is aging in places where no stem cells - like brain - no renew of cells, just existing cells age, damaged, die, and not replaced.

Dolle 2006 found that spontaneous DNA damage in relation to age happened in the liver but not the brain.

Comment: Also you telling us that there is no cancer.

Comment: No & No. The damage is rare, but it does occur so much that cancers may develop naturally in animals and may cause ageing over time. Remember cancer is a huge field of different diseases.

Comment: So how yeast survive? Human stem cells aging and die, or get cancer. But yeast no. Human start from one cell. And die. Yeast start from one cell and live forever (dividing again and again)

Comment: thank you for edition, but you talking about cancer, it's not so good example, my mistake. Sure there is no cancer in single cells. I talking more about aging. Because there is aging in yeast. And one of aging theories for human - accumulating DNA damage. So what Cris writing is that it's really rare. But in humans aging NOT like cancer - it occur in ALL the body and all the cells. So in all cells there are some DNA damage.

Comment: First of all, thank you! About yeast aging and "limited number of..". The yeast has limited number of divisions, mother cell die after some count of them. I am not asking why, I just taking ONE of the theories of human aging (accumulating DNA damage) and asking, if the same theory is right to Yeast, how is it possible that daughter get no damaged DNA, when mother die because it (one of theories).

Comment: About the main part "don't accumulate as much damage" - but the DNA lives 'forever'. It's the same DNA - what meter if it in old cell or in new? One mutation  transferred to daughter. Accumulate new damage (already 2), transfer to new daughter, another damage (already 3) ....

Comment: In my answer I explain that the DNA damage theory of ageing is not directly applicable to yeast as DNA damage theory of ageing affects stem cells and stops repair of tissues, so the whole massive 37 trillion cell human organism suffers. In yeast, the DNA damage doesn't have this affect and 'ageing' in that context does not occur despite there being DNA damage passed down the lineage of cells. What do you mean "DNA lives forever"?

Comment: I don't agree about  repair of tissues. DNA damage leads to problems in cell that damage occurs in. Doesn't meter if it steam or not. Damaged DNA can't make some protein or do bad one. So it's directly  applicable to yeast - in my opinion. Damaged DNA, not producing of important proteins - death.

Comment: About DNA lives forever. You say that there is no time to damage to accumulate because short life. But the DNA it self doesn't have short life. DNA (lets say one of single string) lives forever. And the second string is just a cope. Lets say we have a small damage in mother (G instead of C) and it doesn't influence. It pass to all the daughters. One of daughters take another damage (one A to T) so now we have already 2 damages in DNA. And it's go forward accumulating more and more. It doesn't meter that the initial cell already dead.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't matter what your opinion is; The most current form of the theory of DNA damage based human ageing is that long lived stem cell stocks are depleted. For regular DNA damage you are right. It happens in yeast and humans. But ageing in humans is a more complex systemic and generally predictable process rather than random changes to random proteins. And always remember, this is one of many theories of human ageing and it possible many of those theories are right.

Comment: Damage in stem cell = stem cell not working. Same damage in yeast cell = yeast cell don't work. Also there is aging in places where no stem cells - like brain - no renew of cells, just existing cells age, damaged, die, and not replaced. Aging of stem cells cause by DNA damage (one of the causes) so in the same way it cause damage to yeasts. I talking only about DNA damage and not other theories. The DNA damage have some part in it - that is the theory. So in the same way it need to affect yeast too.

Comment: Damage in stem cell = stem cell not working = no cell renewal = ageing? The brain does not age quicker when DNA damage is increased (see modified answer, Doll et al 2013). Fundamentally you are misunderstanding that yeast and humans propagate in different ways. Another misunderstanding is that this form of ageing does not apply to yeast. But I hope I have helped a little. If you have any more questions or thoughts, feel free to move this to the discussion.

Comment: Thank you, Good Gravy. I will dive dipper in this topic. But about the brain, for example, in wiki "Accumulation of DNA damage with age in brain has been reported during the period 1971 to the present in at least 29 studies" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_damage_theory_of_aging) there is a lot of studies that talking about accumulating damage in all body cells (not just stem). "The source of the DNA damages ... appears to be reactive oxygen species, produced as byproducts of normal cellular metabolism." Yeast produce same  reactive oxygen. Wiki talking about damage to single, not stem, cell

Comment: This is why there are many theories; each has evidence for and against it. Nobody know which contributes the most to ageing. Here we are discussing DNA damage only. The mutation theory is different. Perhaps open another question?

Comment: What meter how many theories is? Also I didn't talked which one more important.. I getting answer to questions that I didn't asked. I telling again and again. DNA damage is one of the theories of aging of single cell in human body (not only stem, regular cells). Because of all the DNA damage (mutation,oxidation,mistakes, doesn't meter) cell lose the function and die. Why it isn't happens in yeast? All your answers very interesting -but that not what I am asking for. There is similarity between yeast cell and human cell. They both get DNA damage, for example from reactive oxygen from metabolism

Comment: "This is why there are many theories; each has evidence for and against it" How is that connected to my comment? I wrote just about one thing - DNA damage.